# Creating IAM user via terraform and upload the secret key and access key in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

I have written a terraform code to  create IAM user and my requirement is to store the access key and secret key in a S3 bucket. I have tried implementing the same via s3 cli commands, but was not of great help. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without knowing we can only guess what you haven't tried yet.

Comment: I tried via s3 copy cli command, but was not of great help

Comment: you can try 2 ways,one using 'local_exec' and one with 'aws_s3_bucket_object' resource.make sure you understand the difference

Comment: correct me I am wrong the secret key and access key needs to be stored in a  file and then upload it by using local exec with aws s3 cp command or go via terraform route and  upload it via aws_s3_bucket_object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to point out that storing tokens in s3 can be dangerous, if not configured correctly.

**Make sure that you have understood how policies in AWS and access control in s3 works!**. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access.html

With that out of the way, this is what I have come up with:

```
# The user to which we will grant access to s3
resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  name          = "s3-user"
  path          = "/"
}

# Create the access key
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "key" {
  user = aws_iam_user.user.name
}

# Create the bucket for storing tokens
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "token" {
  bucket = "my_token_bucket"
  acl    = "private"
}

# Create the object inside the token bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "tokens" {
  bucket                 = aws_s3_bucket.token.id
  key                    = "keys.txt"
  server_side_encryption = "AES256"
  content_type = "text/plain"
  content = <<EOF
access_id: ${aws_iam_access_key.key.id}
access_secret: ${aws_iam_access_key.key.secret}
EOF
}
```

I haven't tested this.

Comment: I have used this way to implement my requirement with a slight change. this definitely fulfills my requirement in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loca-exec to execute commands :

```
resource "null_resource" "s3_copy" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3 cp keys.txt s3://bucket/keys "
  }
}
```