# How to create IAM user with access key and secret key using Serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-iam, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'd like to use Serverless framework to create an IAM user for programmatic access with certain Policies attached to it and export it's Access Key ID and Secret Key as environment variables for lambda. How to achieve that?

(something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70258139/309852) is done with terraform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to add a user with roles and permissions set up. Setting up roles and permissions is important since usually you don't create a user with Access/Secret key in a vacuum, the user needs to have some accesses.

Notes:

- All IAM resources need to have a region in the name since redeployment a resource with the same name will cause an "unrecoverable error" (accordingly to [AWS IAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html))
- To reference the Access Key you just specify resource name, but to reference the Secret Key you need to get property `SecretAccessKey`.
- Sample permissions in the policy give access to an SQS queue, but it can be anything

File `serverless-with-my-user.yml`:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    # Naming an IAM resource can cause an unrecoverable error if you reuse the same template in multiple Regions
    MyUser:
      Type: AWS::IAM::User
      Properties:
        UserName: "my-${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.region}-User"
        Policies:
        - PolicyName: 
            Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - "myUser"
                - '-'
                - ${self:provider.stage}
                - '-'
                - ${self:provider.region}
                - '-MyPolicy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
                - "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
              Resource: { 'Fn::ImportValue': '${self:provider.stage}-MyQueueArn' }
    MyUserKey:
      Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
      Properties: 
        UserName:
          Ref: MyUser

  Outputs:
    MyUserAccessKeyID:
      Description: The Access Key of the MyUser
      Value:
        Ref: MyUserKey
      Export:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-MyUserAccessKeyID
    MyUserAccessSecretKey:
      Description: The ARN of the secret key
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - MyUserKey
          - SecretAccessKey
      Export:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-MyUserAccessSecretKey
```

And here's how to access this user's access key and secret key in other parts of serverless resources (e.g. lambda):

File `serverless-with-my-service.yml`

```
environment:
  MYUSER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
    Fn::ImportValue: '${self:provider.stage}-MyUserAccessKeyID'
  MYUSER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
    Fn::ImportValue: '${self:provider.stage}-MyUserAccessSecretKey'
```

If user, key and service are in a single file, there's no need to use output variables and you can reference the values directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by writing raw CloudFormation in `resources` section: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources.

However, one note - it is not recommended to pass AWS Access Keys directly to Lambda - it's better to use IAM Role that is assigned to Lambda to grant it proper permissions.

EDIT: Example on how to access it

```
provider:
  name: aws
  environment:
    ENVVAR:
      'Fn::GetAtt':
        - MyKey
        - SecretAccessKey

resources:
  Resources:
    MyKey:
      Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
      Properties: 
        Serial: 0
        Status: Active
        UserName: username
```

I want to reiterate once again that it's a really bad idea to do something like the above - you should rely on temporary credentials from assumed role instead.

Comment: Can you provide an example? How to get the values of Access Keys after that declared resource is deployed from within `serverless.yml`?

Comment: Here you have documentation for Access Key - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-accesskey.html you can reference it with CF intrinsic functions

Once again - I would highly advise against using AWS Access Keys passed via environment to Lambda - it's much better to just rely on roles

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you did not provide a serverless.yml example how to use it. I saw that documentation before, but it unclear how one can reference these properties in other parts of serverless.yml file. I need a minimal working example instead of broad link to documentation

Comment: I've added example to the answer

Comment: Thank you for providing a basic example. Can you please add how one declares roles that IAM user with that access key will have access to since that was the original question? Thanks a bunch